# LINQ to XML- only return variables and variable values

Tags: linq-to-sql, asp.net-web-api2

Good day
I am calling an sms client (using C# API v2 [REST])that return xml results as follows:

```
<apiresult>
  <data>
    <credits>100</credits>
  </data>
  <callresult>
    <result>True</result>
    <error />
  </callresult>
</apiresult>
```

By using LINQ to XML, I would like to return the variables to an object, i.e. credits: 100, result : true , and return it as JSON.

I have tried something to the following:

```
//Remove invalid chars
var legalchars = RemoveIllegalChars(Results);

XDocument po = XDocument.Parse(legalchars);
var list1 = po.Root.Descendants("apiresult");
```

without obtaining the desired result. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: In an xml, there are many nodes and nodes inside them. How do you determine which one you want? you can use Json.Net for creating json objects to be sent as a response.

Comment: do you want just credits and result ??

Comment: Hi singsuyash, I have a few more that I want, but once I found the How, the others are easy :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need Newtonsoft.Json package, and i am using XElement:

```
XElement root = XElement.Parse(@"
    <apiresult>
        <data>
            <credits>100</credits>
        </data>
        <callresult>
            <result>True</result>
            <error />
        </callresult>
</apiresult>
    ");

    var credits = root.Element("data").Element("credits").Value;
    var result = root.Element("callresult").Element("result").Value;

    JObject jsonObj = JObject.FromObject(
        new {credits = credits, result = result}
    );

    Console.WriteLine (jsonObj.ToString());
```

Of course instead of writing it to console, `return jsonObj.ToString()`

Comment: Thank you, exactly what I wanted and working like a charm